# How to remove lines with more than x words? in notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to sort a huge list for a project, and I need to delete all the lines from long lists that contain more than 4 words.
anyone knows how could i do this in notepad++?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could come up with sth. like:

```
^(?:\b\w+[^\w\r\n]*){4,}$
# ^   - anchor the expression to the beginning of a line
# (?: - a non capturing group
# \b  - a word boundary
# \w+ - match word characters greedily
# [^\w\r\n] - do not match any of these character (classes) 
# the construct {4,} repeats this pattern 4 or more times
# $   - match the end of the line
```

You need to have the `multiline` mode on. See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pA5vK4/3).
Thanks to @SebastianProske for spotting an error in the original expression.

Comment: Gute Nacht - and more than 4 words would be a repetition of 5 or more

Comment: thanks a lot! works great :) this will save me like 70% of the time by sorting out all the unneeded junk automaticly!

Answer (score 0):

```
\n?^(\S+[^\S\n]+){3,}\S+.*$
```

This works in TextWrangler; It might work in notepad++.